# get root view component ref angular2

Tags: angular

I would like to get root component and insert my component after it.
Here is a code, where I trying to get root component:

```
// get app root view component ref
        if (!this.rootViewContainerRef) {
          this.rootViewContainerRef = this.appRef['_rootComponents'][0]['_nativeElement'].vcRef;

    }
```

but this.rootViewContainerRef is null here. What do I wrong here?

And after get root component I want to do this:

```
this.rootViewContainerRef.createComponent(notificationFactory, this.rootViewContainerRef.length, childInjector);
```

Comment: Did you inject `ViewContainerRef` in your root component?

Comment: Or use location instead of ViewContainerRef as decribed here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9293#issuecomment-261329089

Comment: Thanks. The problem is resolved